# Why can't this process terminate?

Tags: terminal, activity-monitor, macos

[image: o]

Just recently I ran into an issue where my network program couldn't bind to a port because it was already in use. I opened the activity monitor and realized it (named "server") was already running from previously, even though I had closed the window and it was supposedly terminated. Quit or Force Quit on the process do nothing. I even restarted the computer but it was still there! This hasn't happened with my program before. I even typed in the terminal `kill 4517` and nothing happened. Help?

Comment: If the process automatically appeared again after reboot, "something" restarted it for you. What kind of "network program" are we looking at here?

Answer (score 4):

OS X uses a process launching system called *launchd* which consolidates functions provided by Init scripts, crontab and more in *nix systems (see [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) for a high level overview, and [Apple’s Developer docs on launch daemons and agents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ) for details). One of the abilities of *launchd* is to keep a process it launched alive, if so defined by its configuration file – in that case, the process will relaunch whenever it is terminated. Your problem with a process apparently persisting across reboots and manual termination sounds very much like a case of *launchd* initiated process with a `keepAlive` key.

*launchd* configuration files are in *plist* format and found in

- `~/Library/LaunchAgents` – agents for the current  user account only
- `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons` – agents and daemons for all user accounts
- `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` – system level agents and daemons

and are usually named in reverse domain notation (`tld.domain.process.plist`). Depending if the user account of `server` is yours or not (can’t say, as you have blanked it), you should look in one of the first two locations above for a likely plist (if you have Xcode installed, you can QuickLook them easily). If found, your `server` is indeed controlled by launchd. The correct procedure to stop it is to remove it from *launchd*’s process list through

```
launchctl unload <tld.domain.process>
```

which will unload and stop the process (note you omit the `plist` suffix).

There is also a GUI for handling *launchd* files, [Peter Borg’s *Lingon*](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/lingon/id411211026?mt=12) (make sure to get “Lingon”, not “Lingon 3”, which is a dumbed down version safe for vanilla use), which might be more convenient than manually rooting through the file locations.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try.

```
    sudo kill -9 4517
```

Where 4517 is the PID of the process.

If the process comes back with a new PID, something relaunched it.  See kopischke's answer for how to deal with that.